# Background position always bottom

Tags: css

I have a problem with a background image I am trying to always be positioned at the bottom.

[Example page 1](http://dev.web2works.co.uk/word_press/)
[Example page 2](http://dev.web2works.co.uk/word_press/?p=1) where the page is taller and scroll to the bottom you notice that the background is not at the bottom.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I honestly don't see any background (or CSS for that matter) on both those pages.

Comment: Try again now, I have updated the website and added the background to .wrapper

Comment: I see problem, its because the URL is still localhost, let me figure out how to change URL in word press

Comment: Ok fixed now, I didn't realise word press saves the URL in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the body background image in your CSS, apply the property:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

I hope I'm understanding the question correctly, as I believe that property is used for exactly your reason.

Comment: Worked brilliantly. This has always been a little bug there I never knew how to fix until now. Thank you

Comment: No problem at all, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the background on the body, and not on the content area, that's the cause of the background not stretching on your page.

Comment: Thanks, but still problem on example 2. I did try this to start with.

Comment: Depending if I have height: 100% on either body/html it effects the page differently.